# Copy List array object to another array in Angular 9

Tags: node.js, arrays, angular9

I am working with list array in angular. I have a problem in converting a array of list to another array for iteration purpose. below given the sample code.

```
fimage() {
    this.http.get < any > ('<-Apiurl->', { headers: this.header })
        .pipe(map(rese => {
            return { rese }
        }))
        .subscribe((result: any) => {
            this.fimg.push(result);
            this.simg = this.fimg[0].rese.images;
            // console.log(this.fimg);
            this.imgaecount();
        });
}
imgaecount() {
    var loob: any;
    var sec: any;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.simg.length; i++) {
        this.http.get < any > ('<-Apiurl->/' + this.simg[i].id, { headers: this.header })
            .pipe(map(res => {
                return { res }
            }))
            .subscribe((result2: any) => {
                loob = result2.res.image;
                this.ffimg.push(loob);
            });
    }
    console.log(this.ffimg);
}
```

I need to pass the image id to the second api call to get the image details. I got the response as expected but when i pushed the data to an array its showing not like an array. I can't able to iterate the array for the future purpose. below given the sample array structure .

[image]

I really appreciate any help :)

Comment: I also have this same type of problem anyone here to solve this?.

Comment: What does the actual result after pushing to the array look like?

Comment: That is an array and you can iterate through it like this.ffimage[0].status. If you're trying to iterate through it in an ngFor then you should look into the keyvalue pipe

Comment: It depends on the value you are getting as part of the response. Also it is not clear what is the error you getting and where you are facing the error. Are you having issues iterating `this.ffimg` ? If yes where is the logic to iterate. One note this.ffimg.push(loob); is called inside subscribe so it is asynchronous, if you are trying to iterate before value being pushed you might not be able to see the output.

Comment: The pic you posted pretty much looks like an array. What exactly is your problem? (I liked your post, you should now be able to leave a comment)

Comment: @Online ,Thank you for your concern. I have sorted it out.